# Computing frequencies of a set of prepositions in a text file

Tags: python-3.x

How do I open and read a text file and compute the frequencies of prepositions (already specified in a tuple) and create a dictionary with the key the preposition and the value the frequencies.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider revising your question to make sure that you provide us with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that people are able to help you. You should also include your own attempt at the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question correctly.

Here's a simple way to open and read text files:

```
file = open("filename", 'r') #'r' means read mode
content = file.read() #content is a string of the entire text file
content = content.lower() #assuming your tuple of prepositions are lower case
words = content.split() #splits content into list of word separated by space
file.close() #closes the file after you already have the contents
```

Now just trace through your tuple of prepositions:

```
#Let's call your tuple preps
freq = []*len(preps)
for i in range(len(preps)):
    freq[i] = words.count(preps[i])
```

Now to write your key:

```
key = file.open("filename", 'w') #'w' means write mode
key.write("\n".join([prep[i] + " " + str(freq[i]) for i in range(len(prep))]))
key.close()
```